# Google oauth2 javascript client not working in IE 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Although the following code works correctly using Chrome (shows a popup that requests permission from the user to allow access to map and places data), IE 9 opens the popup form, but it is empty; when calling handleAuthClick method. I have tried adding setTimeouts but without effect. I ensured popups are allowed, and checked the popup page urls which are identical in Chrome and IE. Has anyone encountered this problem? Or can someone offer a work-around?

```
var clientId = '############.apps.googleusercontent.com';
var apiKey = '#A#A#A#A##';
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me';

function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
    window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
}

function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true }, handleAuthResult);
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        makeApiCall();
    } else {
    }
}

function handleAuthClick(event) {
    try {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false }, handleAuthResult);
        }, 10);
    } catch (e) { alert(e.message); }
}
function makeApiCall() {
    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function () {
        var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
            'userId': 'me'
        });
        request.execute(function (resp) {
            $(".google-signin").find("img").attr('src', resp.image.url).css('height', '32').css('width', '32');
            $("#login-msg").text('Welcome: ' + resp.displayName);
            $("img.vote").css('visibility', 'visible');

        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ending up solving this issue was increasing the setTimeout duration to 1000 from 10. The Google authorization pop-up was displayed with the correct sing-in information, rather than a blank screen.

Comment: I have the same problem, but this solution did not help. I'm still getting the blank popup instead of the real info...

Comment: Are Pop-up windows enabled? (It is a pity that Google has not offered any solutions).

Comment: yes. popup are allowed in the browser. The popup is shown but with blank content.

Comment: same thing... i get blank popup with IE 11

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that cross-origin scripting between the client web application and Google is blocked by zone security.

Please ensure that both google.com and the webpage where the script is running fall into the same security zone (Internet Zone, typically.) If you aren't sure, see serverfault#612903 https://serverfault.com/questions/612903/ie11-how-to-check-into-which-zone-a-url-falls

Also ensure that the zone in which the web application and Google are classified is configured to allow script execution and ensure third-party cookie access is allowed for google.com as this is used to check for authorization.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response - +1. It turns out that Google rescinded the feature that required OAuth, so this problem is mute,

Answer (score 0):

Note that the maps/feeds scope you are using is for the deprecated Google Maps Data API, which is not the same thing as the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/)

Regarding your actual question, I am retagging to replace Places API with the Plus API since that is what you are using here.

Comment: I have removed all scopes except for google+, but IE (8/9) is still not cooperating.