# OAuth2 not working on IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

In Chrome/FF the following example works fine but there is a problem in IE9.

```
var clientId = 'XXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com';
        var apiKey = 'XXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXh1o';
        var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';

        function handleClientLoad() {
            $(".modal").show();
            gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
            window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
        }

        function checkAuth() {
            gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true },
                handleAuthResult);
        }

        function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
            var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
            if (authResult) {
                authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                showPanel();
            } else {
                authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
                authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
            }
            $(".modal").hide();
        }

        function handleAuthClick(event) {

            gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false }, handleAuthResult);



            return false;
        }


        function showPanel() {
            $("div#mainPanel").show("fast");

        }

        function makeApiCall() {

            gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function () {
                var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
                    'calendarId': 'primary'
                });

                request.execute(function (resp) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
                        var li = document.createElement('li');
                        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(resp.items[i].summary));
                        document.getElementById('events').appendChild(li);
                    }
                });
            });

        }
```

for some reason the `authResult` variable is null in IE9 and `handleAuthClick` click event popup a blank window instead of the Google credentials info.

What's the problem with IE9?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285480/google-oauth2-javascript-client-not-working-in-ie-9

Comment: I saw this post but the answer there did not help so probably it is a different issue...

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/issues/detail?id=42

Comment: @mfirry, the symptoms are the same but it is not the same issue. They have a problem with multi-scope but this is not my case...

Comment: maybe it's a known bug then https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/issues/detail?id=3

Comment: it is hard to believe that there is no solution for such a problem