# Google Oauth2 sign in using javascript API is not working with IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-oauth, google-oauth-java-client

I am using google oauth2 javascript api to authenticate an user to my app. This is working fine in Firefox and chrome, but not in IE. I have tried in IE 8, 9, and 10 but in vain. I searched a lot in net but dint get any solution to it. I have gone through the stackoverflow question [14285480](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285480/google-oauth2-javascript-client-not-working-in-ie-9) and [14830177](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830177/oauth2-not-working-on-ie9). If this is an existing bug in google then is there any alternate method for this?  I am trying below code.
I dont have enough stackoverflow points to comment in any question, so asking a new question. Please help.

Here is my code

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">       
        window.setTimeout(function() {        
            var po = document.createElement('script'); 
            po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;        
            po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';        
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);      
        },1000)(); 

        function signinCallback(authResult) {   
            if (authResult['access_token']) { 
                 document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
            } 
            else if (authResult['error']) {   
                 console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);   
            } 
        }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <span id="signinButton">
        <span 
        class="g-signin" 
        data-callback="signinCallback" 
        data-clientid="my clinetid" 
        data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin" 
        data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"     
        data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile">   
        </span> 
    </span> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">       
function signinCallback(authResult) {   
            if (authResult['access_token']) { 
                 document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');

            } 
            else if (authResult['error']) {   
                 console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);   
            } 
        }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <span id="signinButton">
        <span 
        class="g-signin" 
        data-callback="signinCallback" 
        data-clientid="my clinetid" 
        data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin" 
        data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"     
        data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile">   
        </span> 
    </span>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var po = document.createElement('script'); 
  po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;        
  po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';        
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);      
</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: provide some details if possible.

Comment: What have you changed? Its difficult to compare code