# OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

The following code works well when using Chrome or Firefox. Here is how Chrome/Firefox handles.

1. User clicks on the "Authorize" button.
2. Browser opens a popup window that request for permission to access calendar data.
3. User clicks on the "Accept" button.
4. Popup window closes automatically.

However, it does not work on IE. Here is how IE handles.

1. User clicks on the "Authorize" button.
2. Browser opens a popup window that request for permission to access calendar data.
3. User clicks on the "Accept" button.
4. Popup window becomes blank and does not close automatically.

Has anyone encountered similar problems? Or is there any work-around it? I have been searching for a solution but still could not find any. There seem to be people facing the similar issues too.

- [Google oauth2 javascript client not working in IE 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285480/google-oauth2-javascript-client-not-working-in-ie-9)

The codes below is taken from [Google APIs Client Library for Javascript.](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/source/browse/samples/authSample.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <script src='js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="authorize-button" style="visibility: hidden">Authorize</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
var clientId = '{CLIENT ID}';
var apiKey = '{API KEY}';
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';

function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
    window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
}

function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    console.log(authResult);
    var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        makeApiCall();
    } else {
        authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
        authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
    }
}

function handleAuthClick(event) {
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
    return false;
}

function makeApiCall() {
    gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
        var request = gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list();
        request.execute(function(resp){
            $.each( resp.items, function( key, value ) {
                console.log(resp.items[key].id);
            });
        });
    });
}  
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
<p>Retrieves Calendar ID using the Google Plus API.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATES:**
Tried to figure out what may be wrong and found out "authResult" returns to different results despite having the same code.

Chrome/Firefox Result:

```
[object Object]
{
    _aa: "1",
    access_token: "{ACCESS TOKEN}",
    client_id: "{CLIENT ID}",
    cookie_policy: undefined,
    expires_at: "1414246430",
    expires_in: "3600",
    g_user_cookie_policy: undefined,
    issued_at: "1414160131",
    response_type: "token",
    scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
    state: [object Object],
    token_type: "Bearer"
}
```

IE Result:

```
[object Object]
{
    client_id: "{CLIENT ID}",
    cookie_policy: undefined,
    error: "immediate_failed",
    error_subtype: "access_denied",
    expires_at: "1414246430",
    expires_in: "86400",
    g_user_cookie_policy: undefined,
    issued_at: "1414160030",
    response_type: "token",
    scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
    state: "",
    status: { }
}
```

Comment: Any mileage in the Do Not Track feature being enabled in your installation of IE9? The sample code provided by Google has also, I think, from looking at the sample code as of today, been updated so it might be worthwhile re-visiting the sample code page.